# DDEX samples for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sample, vspackage

I have Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010. I installed the SDK for both.
In the Visual Studio 2008 SDK there are some samples for DDEX in the directories:

Example.BasicProvider

Example.ExtendedProvider

Example.ProviderWithUICustomization

Example.RegistryBasedProvider

Example.VsPackageBasedProvider

Example.VsPackageBasedProvider

I want these same samples but for Visual Studio 2010.
The Visual Studio 2010 SDK does not include these samples, and I can't find anything in Microsoft website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This sample](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFSampleProvider) is up to date and seems to work with Visual Studio 2010. It doesn't include all of your examples, but I found it useful.